# Cannot paste text inside menu item's popup panel

Tags: objective-c, cocoa, nstextfield, nspanel

I have a menu application and I'm launching a NSPanel from a menu item: when the user clicks on the menu item I lazily instantiate a custom NSWindowController (just the first time), and then I show it calling showWindow:

The custom NSViewController is linked to a xib file:

[image]

This is how I create it:

```
// @property (nonatomic,strong) AddFeedController* addFeedController;
- (AddFeedController*) addFeedController
{
    if (!_addFeedController)
    {
        _addFeedController = [[AddFeedController alloc]initWithWindowNibName:@"AddFeedController"];
    }
    return _addFeedController;
}
```

The problem is that if I try to paste some text inside of one of those two text field, it doesn't paste anything and it beeps.

**EDIT**

I managed to restore the original menu (I had to copy it from another project's xib, because only the original is recognized), and I modified the *addFeedController* accessor this way:

```
- (AddFeedController*) addFeedController
{
    if (!_addFeedController)
    {
        _addFeedController = [[AddFeedController alloc]initWithWindowNibName:@"AddFeedController"];
        [_addFeedController.window setLevel: NSPopUpMenuWindowLevel];
    }
    return _addFeedController;
}
```

I also modified the method that displays the window:

```
- (IBAction) launchFeedController : (id) sender
{
    [self.addFeedController showWindow: self];
    // I added these lines:
    [NSApp activateIgnoringOtherApps:YES];
    [self.addFeedController.window makeKeyAndOrderFront:self];
}
```

The first time the panel appears immediately, with no problem. But when I close the panel and try to launch it a second time it doesn't appear.

Comment: Did you keep the Edit menu in the Main XIB or Storyboard? This is needed as it links the cmd-V keyboard shortcut to the paste: action.

Comment: I didn't have it. I re-added it, but now I can copy-paste text just using the submenu item, the key equivalent doesn't work.

Comment: Try calling [NSApp activateIgnoringOtherApps:YES];

Comment: @PierreBernard I'm actually close to the solution. I added the method call that you mentioned and I also made sure that the panel's level is NSPopUpMenuWindowLevel. Now the panel shows the first time, but if I close it and try to relaunch it it doesn't (details in the edit).

Comment: Do you have release "Release When Closed" enabled in Interface Builder?

Comment: @PierreBernard No it's unchecked.